# What do you think of Chatterton

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the following two sentences

> I think of Chatterton, the marvelous boy.
>
> I think of Chatterton as the marvelous boy.

I think the second one is correct but not sure about the first one

Comment: Since he was probably the English poet, shouldn't 'marvellous' have two Ls?

Answer (score 1):

`as the marvelous boy` describes your opinion of Chatterton. For example: `How do you feel about Chatterton? Well I think of him as a marvelous boy.`

For the first sentence, `the marvelous boy` is used to specify which Chatterton you are talking about. It's like if you knew two people with the same name and you want to be specific: `I think of John, the mailman, as a great person.`

Comment: But then first sentence is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatical, although they have different meanings.

> I think of Chatterton, the marvelous boy.

This uses *the marvelous* boy as an [appositive](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/appositive_apposition.htm), a way of adding additional or clarifying information about Chatterton. The sentence has a main or independent clause (before the comma) and a dependent clause (after the comma).

The main clause of the sentence is *I think of Chatterton*. The additional information is nonrestrictive, meaning that the sentence could function on its own without harming the main clause (without changing its essential meaning from the simple fact that you think about him).

---

> I think of Chatterton **as** the marvelous boy.

This describes *what* you think about Chatterton. It's not simply saying that you *do* think of him. The entire sentence is an independent clause—there is no dependent clause.

*As the main boy* is part of the single independent clause. Although the sentence would still make sense if you removed *as the marvelous boy*, it would change its essential meaning—it would no longer be describing *what* you think about the boy, only that you do think about him.